# Which cluster algebras where the existence of maximal green sequences is still unknown?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quivers, cluster-algebras

Maximal green sequences are studied in many papers. For example, [Maximal Green Sequences for Cluster Algebras Associated to the n-Torus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3713) by Eric Bucher, [On Maximal Green Sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2050) by Thomas Brüstle, Grégoire Dupont, Matthieu Pérotin, [Minimal length maximal green sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07313) by Alexander Garver, Thomas McConville, Khrystyna Serhiyenko, [Maximal green sequences for quivers of finite mutation type](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03799) by Matthew R. Mills, [Maximal Green Sequences of Exceptional Finite Mutation Type Quivers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1072) by Ahmet I. Seven.

For which cluster algebras is the existence of maximal green sequences still unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it may be better to ask which quivers have a maximal green sequence. Or ask which cluster algebras have a initial seed with a maximal green sequence. Greg Muller shows in [The existence of a maximal green sequence is not invariant under quiver mutation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04675) that the existence of a maximal green sequence is a property of the quiver not the cluster algebra/mutation class of quiver. In this paper an example a two mutation equivalent quivers is given such that one quiver has a maximal green sequence while the other does not.

Second I mentioned this post to Eric Bucher and he suggested the example of quivers coming from Le diagrams/reduced plabic graphs.

In [Green-to-Red Sequences for Positroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01695) by Ford and Serhiyenko it is shown that cluster algebras arising from Le diagrams have a *green-to-red sequence* (a.k.a. *reddening sequence*). Note that the existence of a green-to-red sequence does only depend on the cluster algebra. Also it is worth noting that these cluster algebra arising from a Le diagram is thought to be the coordinate ring of the corresponding positroid variety. However, the existence of a green-to-red sequence is weaker than the existence of a maximal green sequence. The existence of a maximal green sequence in this case is still open.